# Adjust table to page's height

Tags: html, css, html-table

My HTML page is divided into two sections:

- LEFT : there is a `table`
- RIGHT: there is a `div` including its text

I want that the `table` would be high like the `div`, and it should adjust automatically when the `div`'s height changes.
(I tried it in CSS: `body`, `html`, `table` {height:100%}, but this is not what I want).

**PS:**
The `div` arrives at the bottom of the page, so I can adapt the `table` at the height of the page.
Can someone please help me to do this?

Comment: Please create a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of your problem and code so the community can better answer your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

i think that, you can try use variable in css, and then substitute it for table height and div. I don't know exactly what, you mean.

PS. maybe you should use this selector: table, div { min-height: ... ;}

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about having equal heights on both columns, this can easily be achieved with Flexbox.

Check this page out

`https://davidwalsh.name/flexbox-column`